# cdata noting closing in asp.net xml

Tags: asp.net, xml, visual-studio-2010

I am making a project with asp.net loading xml files

in one of the xml files i have a question and i want to display a picture and flash in different questions.

```
<![CDATA[<a><img src="Study/1.png"/><a>]]>
```

that is the code i using in my xml, my problem is its displaying both flash content and images fine but it is not closing the cdata property i.e

> ]]>
>    directly after an image or object.

any ideas?

heres my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<quiz xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="quiz.xsd">
<mchoice>
    <question>For aircraft flying over the high seas, which rules shall be in force?  <![CDATA[<a><img src="Study/1.png"/></a>]]></question>
    <answer>The rules established by the state(s) adjacent to the high seas over flown </answer>
    <answer>The rules established by the state of the operator of the aircraft </answer>
    <answer correct="yes">The rules established by the state of registry of the aircraft </answer>
    <answer>The rules established under the Convention of international civil aviation </answer>
</mchoice>
     </quiz>
```

here is my schema

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"    elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:element name="quiz">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="mchoice" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="question" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="answer" minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:simpleContent>
                                        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:attribute name="correct" use="optional">
                                            <xs:simpleType>
                                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                                    <xs:enumeration value="yes"/>
                                                    <xs:enumeration value="no"/>
                                                </xs:restriction>
                                            </xs:simpleType>
                                               </xs:attribute>
                                         </xs:extension>
                                </xs:simpleContent>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
 </xs:schema>
```

here is my asp.net code for the xml

```
   Public Shared Function GetQuizDataFromXML(ByVal XMLFileName As String) As ArrayList
    Dim strXmlFilePath As String = XMLFileName
    Dim xDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
    xDoc.Load(strXmlFilePath)
    Dim Arl As New ArrayList
    If Not IsNothing(xDoc) AndAlso xDoc.SelectNodes("/quiz/mchoice").Count > 0 Then
        Dim TotalQuestions As Integer = 0
        TotalQuestions = xDoc.SelectNodes("/quiz/mchoice").Count
        For i As Integer = 1 To TotalQuestions
            Dim strXPath As String = ""
            strXPath = "/quiz/mchoice[" & i.ToString() & "]"
            Dim oQ As New Questions
            oQ.QuestionID = i + 1
            oQ.Question = xDoc.SelectSingleNode(strXPath & "/question").InnerXml
            Dim xNodeList As XmlNodeList
            xNodeList = xDoc.SelectNodes(strXPath & "/answer")
            For j As Integer = 0 To xNodeList.Count - 1
                Dim oA As New Answers
                oA.QuestionID = oQ.QuestionID
                oA.Answer = xNodeList.Item(j).InnerText
                oA.AnswerID = j + 1
                Dim xNodeAttr As Object
                'Extract correct answer
                xNodeAttr = xNodeList.Item(j).Attributes.ItemOf("correct")
                oA.IsAnswer = False
                If Not xNodeAttr Is Nothing Then
                    If xNodeAttr.Value = "yes" Then
                        oA.IsAnswer = True
                    End If
                End If
                oQ.Answers.Add(oA)
            Next
            Arl.Add(oQ)
        Next
    End If
    Return Arl
    End Function
```

Comment: I don't think you have given us enough to work with. Maybe include more of your XML and/or your C#/VB.NET code .

Comment: ive actually followed pretty much this whole tutorial    http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2786/Online-Quiz    seems simple enough, all is working but just when i put in anything i get the ]]> after the image..

Comment: Post more of your XML. Could be a simple typo.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try putting the entire question in the `CDATA` section as below

```
<question>
    <![CDATA[For aircraft flying over the high seas, which rules shall be in force? <a><img src="Study/1.png"/></a>]]>
</question>
```

If that doesn't solve your problem then work through the problem. Start with what works and add complexity until something breaks. For example, modify the `<question>` tag in this order (the first one should work).

1. `<question>This is a test question</question>`
2. `<question><![CDATA[This is a test question inside a CDATA tag]]></question>`
3. `<question><![CDATA[This is a test question inside a CDATA tag with a <a>link</a>]]></question>`
4. `<question><![CDATA[This is a test question inside a CDATA tag with a <a>link</a> and an image <img src="Study/1.png" />]]></question>`
5. `<question><![CDATA[This is a test question inside a CDATA tag with a linked image <a><img src="Study/1.png" /></a>]]></question>`

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because the `<a>` tag isn't closed ? It should be `</a>`.

**Update**

Well, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the markup of the `CDATA` section, as per the [W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-cdata-sect).

However, since you're using ASP.net, according to [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256076.aspx), you could try replacing `]]>` with `] ]>`, and see if that works.

Comment: still the same after trying that unforantly, thanks all the same :)